# How can I use wildcard with exception in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, wildcard, glob

I want to grep multiple files in a folder. I want to grep everyone of them except big files like pcap file and gziped files. So I am trying :

```
$ grep foo !({*pcap*,*gz*})
```

But that does not work. Because while it avoid gziped files, the shell expansion of `!({*pcap*,*gz*})` returns pcap files actually. Any idea how to include every files except pcap and gziped files please?

Comment: @fedorqui Looks like the daily limit for VTC has gone down.  I'm at 0!

Comment: @devnull there is a lot about closing in Meta these days. I guess the ultimate solution will be to have 1 close vote a day and 50 review tokens :)

Comment: @fedorqui The downside with 1 close vote would be that the system would be flooded with FAQs that wouldn't be closed and answering those wouldn't make much sense either.

Comment: @devnull Yes, I agree. There are a lot of duplicates coming in "our" tags every day that we do not clean fast enough and get plenty of answers.

Comment: @fedorqui my question is more general than grep.

Comment: Apologies; I voted to close too soon. See my answer for a way to restrict what a glob pattern expands too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to change that to

```
grep foo  !(*pcap*|*gz*)
```

to exclude `pcap` and `gz` files

Comment: You'll also need to enable extended patterns with `shopt -s extglob`, if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 6):

The `GLOBIGNORE` parameter lists files to exclude from the results of a glob expansion:

Assuming the current directory is empty:

```
$ touch foo1 foo2 foo3 foo10 foo11 foo12
$ GLOBIGNORE="foo1*:foo3"
$ ls *
foo2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have extended patterns available you could also use multiple --exclude options:

```
grep foo * --exclude "*.pcap" --exclude "*.gz"
```